# How to bulk redirect URLs and replace one path segment?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, url-rewriting

I have several URLs in a WordPress website I would like to rewrite and then make a 301 redirect.

URLs are of the form

```
www.example.com/prodotto/something-after
```

These URLs should be changed to

```
www.example.com/shop/something-after
```

Should I use URL rewrite rules in `.htaccess`? I have used this rule, but it doesn't work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?prodotto/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/shop/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress'
```

Comment: "I would like to rewrite and then make a 301 redirect" - Rewriting first doesn't make sense (at least not in this instance). You simply want to 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/?stringtochange/(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/newstring/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The string after **stringtochange** is passed to the other *url* containing **newstring** in the `$1` variable.

So for example, if you access `www.example.com/stringtochange/cool-page.html` it will get redirected to `www.example.com/newstring/cool-page.html`.

Comment: Just tried without success. I post above here my new htaccess file. You can see your rule close to the end

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: Simply it shows the same old urls

Comment: @bobrock4 The order of these directives is important. The above `RewriteRule` (redirect) needs to go _before_ your existing WordPress directives. By placing the rule _after_ the WP rewrites it will never be executed (because the WP front controller rewrites _everything_). As a general rule, _external redirects_ should always come **before** _internal rewrites_.